# Can I add facts in a drl file prior to rule firing (basically "before" the "when" clause)?

Tags: drools

I am thinking about generating (or "compiling") drl files coming out of a separate data model. Ideally, I'd like to have the drl file be as self-contained as possible and not require a lot of interaction with corresponding java code (to insert facts, set globals etc).

I know I can declare fact (classes) inside the drl rule and I can insert facts in the "then" consequence.
I also know I can use globals to use inside the rule, but I need to explicitly set them in my session (i.e. in java code).

Is there a way to add fact instances to the working memory prior to the rule being fired but still outside of any Java code?

Sample code:

```
declare SomeFact end;

// pseudo code as I dont know if its possible
$listOfStrings = {"one", "two", "three"}; 

rule "some name"

when 
    $someFact:SomeFact($code:code)
    $listOfStrings contains $code

then
    // ...
```

The idea being that at drl creation time I know I will need a certain set of facts within my rule to check against. Now is it possible to have those inserted for me outside of any java code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have it all in a DRL file you may use the following pattern:

```
declare SomeFact
    code: String
end

rule kickoff
  salience 999999999
when
then
  // initialize globals, if necessary
  // insert facts      
  insert( new SomeFact( "one" ) );
end
```

And the rule can be written as

```
rule "some name"
when 
  $someFact: SomeFact( code in ("one", "two", "three") )
then
  // ...
end
```